# regex extract text inside quotes

Tags: regex

In Javascript, I'm storing found regex entries to a JSON array.  The stored entries contain the encapsulating single quotes--but I don't want them to.

The string I'm checking looks like this:

```
{{ 'Foo' | i18n:['bar'] }}
```

The regex expression looks like so:

```
('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')
```

This will return `'foo'` and `'bar'` when I just want it to return `foo` and `bar`.

I have the ability to just do a `.replace(/'/g. '');` but that doesn't help if there's an escaped single quote like so:

```
{{ 'foo\'s' | i18n }}
```

Comment: Please provide some more info on your environment.  OS, program you are trying to do the regex in, etc.  Not all regex engines are created equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing group to capture the previous charcater which must not be a backslash.

```
.replace(/(^|[^\\])'/g, '$1');
```

`$1` refers the charcaters which are captured by the first group.

**Example:**

```js
var s = "{{ 'foo\\'s' | i18n }}"
alert(s.replace(/(^|[^\\])'/g, '$1'))
```